# Is it possible to sum the results of a Map - Apply?

Tags: performance-tuning, functional-style, dataset

I am fairly new to functional programming and would like to replace a `For[]` loop that sums the results over a Dataset.

This may be a bit different since the function being called takes a mix of parameters and Dataset columns.

```
activeSegments = segmentMap[Select[#State == 1 &]];
eFieldMag375 = 
  Parallelize[Table[{x, y, segmentMapEFieldIntensity[x, y, 0.375, 37, 10^-8]}, 
    {x,-6,6,0.25},{y,-6,6,0.25}]]

segmentMap = 
  Dataset[{
    <|"id"->1,  "alignType"->0, "x1"->-3.0, "x2"->3.0, "y1"->3.0, "y2"->3.0, "z1"->0.0, "z2"->0.0,   "State"->0|>,
    <|"id"->2, "alignType"->1,  "x1"->0.0, "x2"->0.0, "y1"->-3.0, "y2"->3.0, "z1"->0.0, "z2"->0.0,   "State"->0|>,  
    <|"id"->3, "alignType"->0,  "x1"->-3.0, "x2"->3.0, "y1"->-3.0, "y2"->-3.0, "z1"->0.0, "z2"->0.0, "State"->0|>,
    <|"id"->4, "alignType"->2,  "x1"->0.0,  "x2"->0.0, "y1"->0.0, "y2"->0.0, "z1"->0.0, "z2"->1.5, "State"->0|>,
    <|"id"->5, "alignType"->0, "x1"->-3.0, "x2"->3.0, "y1"->3.0, "y2"->3.0, "z1"->1.5, "z2"->1.5,   "State"->0|>,
    <|"id"->6, "alignType"->1, "x1"->-3.0, "x2"->-3.0, "y1"->-3.0, "y2"->3.0, "z1"->1.5, "z2"->1.5, "State"->0|>,
    <|"id"->7, "alignType"->1, "x1"->3.0, "x2"->3.0, "y1"->-3.0, "y2"->3.0, "z1"->1.5, "z2"->1.5, "State"->0|>,
    <|"id"->8, "alignType"->0, "x1"->-3.0, "x2"->3.0, "y1"->-3.0, "y2"->-3.0, "z1"->1.5, "z2"->1.5,   "State"->0|>,
    <|"id"->9, "alignType"->2, "x1"->-3.0, "x2"->-3.0, "y1"->3.0, "y2"->3.0, "z1"->0.0, "z2"->1.5, "State"->1|>,
    <|"id"->10, "alignType"->2, "x1"->-3.0, "x2"->-3.0, "y1"->-3.0, "y2"->-3.0, "z1"->0.0, "z2"->1.5, "State"->1|>,
    <|"id"->11, "alignType"->2, "x1"->3.0, "x2"->3.0, "y1"->3.0, "y2"->3.0, "z1"->0.0, "z2"->1.5, "State"->1|>,
    <|"id"->12, "alignType"->2, "x1"->3.0, "x2"->3.0, "y1"->-3.0, "y2"->-3.0, "z1"->0.0, "z2"->1.5, "State"->1|>}];

segmentMapEFieldx[testPtx_, testPty_, testPtz_, εr_, ρℓ_]:= 
  Module[{segmentIndex, segmentCount, exMag},
    exMag = 0.0;
    segmentCount = Length[activeSegments];
    For[segmentIndex = 1, segmentIndex <= segmentCount, segmentIndex += 1,
      exMag += Apply[EFieldxComponent,
       {activeSegments[segmentIndex]["alignType"], εr, testPtx, testPty, testPtz, 
        activeSegments[segmentIndex]["x1"], activeSegments[segmentIndex]["x2"],  
        activeSegments[segmentIndex]["y1"], activeSegments[segmentIndex]["y2"],
        activeSegments[segmentIndex]["z1"], activeSegments[segmentIndex]["z2"],
        ρℓ}];]      
    Return[exMag]]

EFieldxComponent[segType_, εr_, x_, y_, z_, xp1_, xp2_, yp1_, yp2_, zp1_, zp2_, ρℓ_]:=
  Switch[segType,
    0, Exx[x, y, z, xp1, xp2, yp1, zp1, εr, ρℓ],
    1, Eyx[x, y, z, xp1, yp1, yp2, zp1, εr, ρℓ],
    2, Ezx[x, y, z, xp1, yp1, zp1, zp2, εr, ρℓ]];
```

The Apply is fairly straight-forward.  I am wondering if it would be possible to replace the For loop with a `Map` and sum the values returned by `EFieldxComponent`.

Comment: Try `Total@` before your output list.

Comment: Thanks David - I will try that.  (Still trying to figure out how to wrap a Map around the Apply so that it iterates over activeSegments).

Comment: you should provide a working example..

Comment: So activeSegments is a list? Of what dimension? Are you not passing it in with the other arguments to the function? And EFieldxComponents is a function?

Comment: I have fleshed out the code snippet to show  activeSegments and EFieldxComponents and the call I am using to create a Table.

Comment: still a number of undefined things in there (`Exx` .. ) , and you don't show how you use `segmentMapEFieldx` .

Answer (score 1):

There may be better approaches, but this is what I found to work.  I replaced:

```
segmentMapEFieldx[testPtx_, testPty_, testPtz_, \[CurlyEpsilon]r_, \[Rho]\[ScriptL]_]:=     
Module[
    {segmentIndex, segmentCount, exMag},

    exMag = 0.0;
    segmentCount = Length[activeSegments];

    For[segmentIndex = 1, segmentIndex<=segmentCount,segmentIndex+=1,
        exMag += Apply[ EFieldxComponent, {activeSegments[segmentIndex]["alignType"],
                                  \[CurlyEpsilon]r, testPtx,testPty,testPtz, 
                                  activeSegments[segmentIndex]["x1"], activeSegments[segmentIndex]["x2"],  
                                  activeSegments[segmentIndex]["y1"], activeSegments[segmentIndex]["y2"],
                                  activeSegments[segmentIndex]["z1"], activeSegments[segmentIndex]["z2"],
                                 \[Rho]\[ScriptL]}];

    ];

    Return[exMag]
]
```

With:

```
segmentMapEFieldx[testPtx_, testPty_, testPtz_, \[CurlyEpsilon]r_, \[Rho]\[ScriptL]_]:=
    Total@Map[(Apply[EFieldxComponent[#2,\[CurlyEpsilon]r, testPtx,testPty,testPtz,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,\[Rho]\[ScriptL]]&,#])&,activeSegments]
```

This dropped AbsoluteTiming for 44.54 seconds to 29.07

Answer (score 0):

This is similar, but perhaps a bit more readable than yours:

```
exMag=Total@Map[
   EFieldxComponent[#["alignType"], \[CurlyEpsilon]r, testPtx, testPty,
        testPtz, #["x1"], #["x2"], #["y1"], #["y2"], #["z1"],
                 #["z2"], \[Rho]\[ScriptL]] &, activeSegments]
```

alternately you might use the `Dataset`  built in map functionality:

```
 Total@activeSegments[All, 
    EFieldxComponent[#["alignType"], \[CurlyEpsilon]r, testPtx, testPty,
    testPtz,#["x1"], #["x2"], #["y1"], #["y2"], #["z1"], #["z2"],
      \[Rho]\[ScriptL]] & ]
```

Can't test due to missing info though.